# Why is my .FBX scene exporting with only one image texture applied to each mesh, when I have multiple?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, .fbx, photogrammetry

I'm trying to export a scene from blender and use it in UE5, but the image textures are all wrong when I export it. I have a few image textures for each mesh, but it seems that only one is applied for each, causing some very weird looking texturing when exported.

note: the objects in the scene are photogrammetry scans

here is my scene:
[image: my scene with image textures applied correctly]

here is the exported .FBX:
[image: my exported .fbx with spooky looking texture, this is the problem]

and these are my .FBX export settings:
[image: my .fbx export settings which I believe are correct for what I'm trying to do]

here is an example of the three image textures present on a single mesh in the scene:
[image: here is an example of the three image textures present on a single mesh in the scene]

Maybe it is something to do with UV maps, which I admittedly know little about... I wonder also if there is a way to 'merge' all three image textures into the same image, maybe that's a dumb question. anyway thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you please share the inside material view of all materials? You can merge them into one image by baking all the textures.

Comment: hey Muzammil, thanks for the response. I'm afraid I don't know what that means, what is the inside material view?

Comment: I mean this one.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K3gE.jpg

Comment: @Muzammil i see, thanks. https://i.imgur.com/ndAxaFh.png here's the one for material in slot 1 of this object. it's just an image texture plugged into the base color

Comment: Having multiple materials on one object shouldn't be a problem. However, the materials can. Using the principbled shader with just values and UV mapped textures is the most standardized and well supported material setup for export. Are all your materials built this way? Otherwise, that might be the reason of the issue.